# Conjoining IP (DNS) Port Scan & IP Odd Network Host Clac Script with Windows Event Viewer

Tags: python, networking, cmd, port, event-viewer

I don't want full answers with this question, only advice (as answers will take the fun away from it)

I have created a script (First year UNI student) that does two things. It can calculate odd number IP hosts network addresses and/or can scan an IP address, or website for open ports (ports 79-81)

I also have another script, created by one of my teachers for another subject. This script is just a test script (just prints whatever into a shell, which is then picked up by Windows 10 Event Viewer)

Now what I want to do (for extra credit, as I have already passed this subject) is to combine these two scripts together (so the port scan, and odd network host calculator) script is picked up in Event Viewer, when i run the script in CMD.

Please resist, from providing me the full answer, just give me a few hints or tips, as its more fun for me.

I post the two scripts that I wish to combine below:

**Odd Number Host Clac & Port Scan**

```
1    import ipaddress #imports a list of ipaddresses
2    import socket #imports a library for port scan function
3    import sys #for notepads
4    
5    
6    
7    
8    def f1(): #networx prefix calc
9        try:
10           network = input('please input network address with the prefix: ') #user enters ip address
11           network = ipaddress.ip_network(network) #variable  is assigned to ipaddress library
12           print(network) #network is displayed in output
13   
14       except ValueError:
15           print('That is not a network address')  #displays if incorrect error
16   
17       iplist= list(ipaddress.ip_network(network).hosts()) #variable is assigned to list
18       for i in range(10,len(iplist),2): #excludes first 10, skips every 2nd ip address to display odd number ip
19           print(iplist[i])#prints the list
20   
21       with open('oddnetworks.txt', 'w') as notepad1: #opens a notepad file for editing
22           print(*iplist, file=notepad1, sep='\n') #writes iplist to notepad file
23   
24   
25   
26   def f2():  #port scan
27       result ='' #assigns a variable for a range list
28       s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)  #variable  is assigned to socket library
29       target = input("what website to scan?: ") #user enters ip or dns
30       def pscan(port):#creates a function
31           try: #trys  lines of code
32               con = s.connect((target, port)) #scans ports
33               return True #return if true
34           except:
35               return False
36       for x in range(79,82): #determines the ports to scan
37           if pscan(x) > pscan(int(x)): #determines if a ports is open
38               print("port ",x," is open")  #prints port is open
39               result = result + " port "+ str(x) + " is open\n" #adds result to range list
40           else:
41               print("port ",x," is closed")  #prints port is closed
42               result = result + " port " + str(x) + " is closed\n" #adds result to range list
43   
44       notepad2 = open('portscan.txt', 'w') #opens notepad file for edit
45       notepad2.write(result) #writes to notepad file
46   
47   
48   def f3():  #exits the program
49       sys.exit()
50   
51   
52   #user input section
53   print("Please enter 'network' to calculate odd number IP address ranges")
54   print("Please enter 'port' to scan ports 79-82")
55   print("to exit this program, enter 'exit'")
56   
57   
58   
59   
60   valid_input = False #assigns a variable to false
61   while not valid_input: #creates a loop
62       q1 = input("please input your choice:  ")
63       if q1 == "network":
64           f1() #runs a function
65           valid_input = True #runs if input is valid
66       elif q1 == "port":
67           f2() #runs a function
68           valid_input = True #runs if input is valid
69       elif q1 == "exit":
70           f3() #runs a function
71           valid_input = True #runs if input is valid
72       else:
73           print("incorrect input, try again")
74   
75
```

***Event Viewer script***

```
1    import win32evtlogutil
2    import win32evtlog
3    import sys
4    
5    print("Python {0} on {1}".format(sys.version,sys.platform))
6    
7    variable = ["x,","y","z"]
8    
9    
10   App_Name = "Python test"
11   App_Event_ID = 10001
12   App_Event_Category = 90
13   #App_Event_Type = win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE
14   App_Event_Str = ["scanned: {}".format(var) for var in variable]
15   App_Event_Data= b"your input here"
16   
17   ''' 
18    
19   win32evtlogutil.ReportEvent(ApplicationName, EventID, EventCategory,EventType,Inserts, Data, SID) 
20    
21   '''
22   
23   
24   win32evtlogutil.ReportEvent(App_Name,App_Event_ID, eventCategory= App_Event_Category,
25                                   eventType=win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
26                                   strings=App_Event_Str,data=App_Event_Data)
27
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out how to conjoin the scripts myself, I post the completed code.

```
1    import ipaddress
2    import socket
3    import sys
4    import win32evtlogutil
5    import win32evtlog
6    
7    def f2():  #port scan
8        result ='' #assigns a variable for a range list
9        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)  #variable  is assigned to socket library
10       target = input("what website to scan?: ") #user enters ip or dns
11       def pscan(port):#creates a function
12           try: #trys  lines of code
13               con = s.connect((target, port)) #scans ports
14               return True #return if true
15           except:
16               return False
17       for x in range(79,82): #determines the ports to scan
18           if pscan(x) > pscan(int(x)): #determines if a ports is open
19               print("port ",x," is open")  #prints port is open
20               result = result + " port "+ str(x) + " is open\n" #adds result to range list
21           else:
22               print("port ",x," is closed")  #prints port is closed
23               result = result + " port " + str(x) + " is closed\n" #adds result to range list
24   
25       notepad2 = open('portscan.txt', 'w') #opens notepad file for edit
26       notepad2.write(result) #writes to notepad file
27   
28       eventviewer = [result]
29   
30       App_Name = "Python Port Scan"
31       App_Event_ID = 10002
32       App_Event_Category = 91
33       # App_Event_Type = win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE
34       App_Event_Str = ["{}".format(result) for result in eventviewer]
35       App_Event_Data = b"result"
36   
37       ''' 
38    
39    
40       win32evtlogutil.ReportEvent(ApplicationName, EventID, EventCategory, EventType, Inserts, Data, SID) 
41    
42       '''
43   
44       win32evtlogutil.ReportEvent(App_Name,App_Event_ID, eventCategory= App_Event_Category,
45                                       eventType=win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
46                                       strings=App_Event_Str,data=App_Event_Data)
47   
48   
49   
50   
51   
52   
53   def f3():  #exits the program
54       sys.exit()
55   
56   
57   #user input section
58   
59   print("Please enter 'port' to scan ports 79-82")
60   print("to exit this program, enter 'exit'")
61   
62   
63   
64   
65   valid_input = False #assigns a variable to false
66   while not valid_input: #creates a loop
67       q1 = input("please input your choice:  ")
68       if q1 == "port":
69           f2() #runs a function
70           valid_input = True #runs if input is valid
71       elif q1 == "exit":
72           f3() #runs a function
73           valid_input = True #runs if input is valid
74       else:
75           print("incorrect input, try again")
```